# How do I copy security information when creating a new folder?

Tags: c#, .net, security, filesystems

In my app I'm creating folders for archiving old stuff from a harddisc.

When creating a new folder I must copy all NTFS rights (Groups / Users) from the source folder to the newly created destination folder.

Here is what I've written so far:

```
FileSecurity fileSecurity =
    File.GetAccessControl(filenameSource, AccessControlSections.All);
FileAttributes fileAttributes = File.GetAttributes(filenameSource);
File.SetAccessControl(filenameDest, fileSecurity);
File.SetAttributes(filenameDest, fileAttributes);
```

Is this really all I ought to do or am I missing something important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is a folder, then you may would want to check [`Directory.SetAccessControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol.aspx) Method. You may would want to call [`DirectorySecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(isProtected/*true*/,preserveInheritance /*false*/)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection.aspx) if you want to prevent the files from inheriting ACL rules, before calling Directory.SetAccessControl();

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a `Process` and call the [XCOPY](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) command? It can copy permissions.

Comment: Because I need it in my own application created in C#.Net ;-) Thanks for trying to help.